# "Котування", "котирування", "квотування" - як правильно?

Tags: терміни, віддієслівні-іменники, іншомовні-слова

Більшість словників видають "котирування". Цей термін означає встановлення курсу цінних паперів, іноземних валют і цін товарів на біржах відповідно до чинних законодавчих норм, правил і практики.

В той же час, за нормами було б правильно вимовляти "котування". До речі, [Вікіпедія подає саме такий варіант](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F).

В словнику синонімів Караванського і на "котування", і на "котирування" вказується синонім "квотування".

Я схиляюся до того, що варто писати "квотування", хоча б тому, щоб не пролетіти з "котуванням" і "котируванням". Хоча, на фін. біржах у вжитку саме "котирування".

Все ж, як правильно? На інших ресурсах, де це питання обговорювалось, ні на чому так і не зупинилися.

Answer (score 2):

Це правда, що суфікси -ир-/-ір- для української мови не дуже характерні. Однак все вирішується традиціями вжитку конкретних слів: деякі слова можна лише без -ир-/-ір-, деякі слова можна і так, і так (деякі слова були раніше нормативними з -ир-/-ір-, але набувають тенденції вживання без -ир-/-ір-), деякі слова наразі вживаються лише з -ир-/-ір-; в деяких випадках без -ир-/-ір- і з -ир-/-ір- — то два різних слова (*панування* і *панірування*). Переважна більшість словників надають *котирувати* і *котирування* станом на початок 2018 лише з -ир-/-ір-, наприклад: [«Словник української мови»](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index) в 20 томах 2010-х років, [«Словники України on-line»](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) від УМІФ 2008 року, [«Економічний словник»](http://library.nlu.edu.ua/POLN_TEXT/KNIGI/KONDOR/EKONOMIC_SL_2006.pdf) Завадського 2006 року, [«Тлумачний словник економіста»](http://shron1.chtyvo.org.ua/Honcharov_Stanislav/Tlumachnyi_slovnyk_ekonomista.pdf) Гончарова 2009 року. Навіть нове (5-те) видання [«Практичного словника синонімів української мови»](http://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Karavanskyy_Sviatoslav/Praktychnyi_slovnyk_synonimiv_ukrainskoi_movy_5-te_vyd_2014/) Караванського від 2014 року вже не містить варіантів без -ир-/-ір-.

Щодо слів *квотувати* і *квотування*, то, незважаючи на те, що обидва гнізда — *квота*/*квотувати*/*квотування* і *котирувати*/*котирування* — походять від одного латинського гнізда *quot*/*quotus* (можливо, через різні мови: через англійську у випадку -квот- і через французьку у випадку -кот-), в сучасній українській мові вони мають різне значення: [квотувати](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=174862&page=1305) — запроваджувати допустимі норми (часто — кількості/обсягу чогось), [котирувати](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=44539&page=1411) — оголошувати біржовий курс (ціну, за якою покупець/продавець згоден купити/продати). Щодо «Практичного словника синонімів української мови» Караванського, то він часто наводить дуже віддалені часткові синоніми (а не лише повні синоніми); можливо, в якихось значеннях *квотувати* і *котирувати* взаємозамінні або в дуже широкому розумінні мають щось спільне — але найвідоміші значення цих слів різні.